# No enclosing instance of type Camera is accessible

Tags: android

I have the following code

```
android.hardware.Camera.Size size = new android.hardware.Camera.Size(300, 300);
```

I get the following compilation error

```
No enclosing instance of type Camera is accessible
```

However, I check the documentation, it is a public constructor

[Android Camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html#Camera.Size%28int,%20int%29)

Anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
Size size = cam.new Size(100, 100);
```

Not entirely sure why this is needed, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: OK. This seems to be a non static inner class.

Comment: Wow! never saw calling `new` on an instance variable! Must be some kind of esoteric usage, but I love it! +1